# How to upload file directly from a webpage?

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

i am generating barcode from the website barcodes4.me.
it generates an image on the url:http://www.barcodes4.me/barcode/qr/myfilename.png?value=My%20QR%20Code.
now i want to save (upload) this file on a click event of a button.
any idea how to do that

Comment: I've got some ideas, but it would be better to know what you've tried so far so answers can be specific to the problem you're having.

Comment: By the way, you would be downloading the image and saving it on your web server. Not uploading the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private static System.Drawing.Image GetImg(string url)
{
    System.Drawing.Image tmpimg = null;
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    var httpWebReponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream stream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream();
    tmpimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
    return tmpimg;
}
```

And put this line in your click event handler:

```
GetImg("http://www.barcodes4.me/barcode/qr/myfilename.png?value=My%20QR%20Code").Save(Server.MapPath("~/Images") + "/barcode.png");
```